# When a user resizes the window, the page layout changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, percentage

I have a div that i set its width to 40%. When the user resizes the page, the size of the div changes according to the resize window. I want a javascript or jquery code that locks the setting of the div to 40% of full screen only no matter what is the size of the current window. In other words, when the user resizes the window, the 40% size of the div stays locked relative to the full screen.

```
<div  style="width: 40%;">
<ul>
<a href="myBio.html"><li>My Bio</li></a>
<a href="favGam.html"><li>favorite Games</li></a>
<a href="jibPuz.html"><li>Jigsaw puzzle</li></a>
<a href="tabOfElm.html"><li>Table of Elements</li></a>
<a href="calc.html"><li>Calculator</li></a>
<a href="recBok.html"><li>Recommended Books</li></a>
<a href="canCod.html"><li>Canadian CoR&F </li></a>
<a href="newtLaw.html"><li>Newtons Law of Gravity</li></a>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you get the width of the current window size and multiply by 0.4 and give it to the width of the element you want.

```
function setWidth (){
 var getWidth = window.innerWidth * 0.4;
 $('elem').css('width', getWidth + 'px');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 setWidth();
});
```

Hope this is what you are searching for :)

Comment: Your code worked when i changed window.innerWidth to window.screen.width. This way the size of the div is relative to the screen instead of the window size. Thanks a lot.

Comment: your welcome. Do not forget to hit the green tick :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use JS to do this.

```
function resize() {
    $("#yourDiv").css("width", screen.width * 0.4);
}
$(window).resize(resize);
resize();
```

Give your div an ID.

Comment: I don't think he wants the "resize" logic.

Comment: > when the user resizes the window, the 40% size of the div stays locked relative to the full screen.
My understanding of his question is that this is what he wants.

Comment: But won't the resize do, basically nothing? The screen.width * 0.4 will always be the same thing. The screen doesn't change resolution on window resize, so it will always be the same number, it's just unnecessary. Otherwise your answer looks like the right one and should be accepted.